# "parameter count mismatch" while invoking method

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing c# with wpf application and I'm getting this error

> parameter count mismatch

while invoking the `DoDisplay` method. I don't know which parameter is missing?

Here is my code

```
public System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox _displayWindow = new System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox();

 public void DisplayData(messageType type, String msg)
 {
     _displayWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new EventHandler(DoDisplay));
 }

 public void DoDisplay(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    try {
       _displayWindow.Selection.Text  = string.Empty;
       _displayWindow.AppendText(_msg);
       _displayWindow.ScrollToEnd();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
    }
 }
```

Comment: What do you expect to be in the `sender` and `e` arguments when `DoDisplay` is invoked by the Dispatcher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dispatcher.Invoke` takes `Action`, i.e. the `delegate` with no parameters. As you are not using `sender` and `EventArgs` in your method then change your Method as:

```
public void DoDisplay()
{
}
```

and its call to:

```
_displayWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => DoDisplay()));
```

If you want to use your `delegate` to be called, then you will have to have pass the Arguments with the call:

```
_displayWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(YOURDELEGATE, YOURPARAMETERS)
```

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question, you need to provide the parameters DoDisplay needs when invoking it with the dispatcher, like so:

```
_displayWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new EventHandler(DoDisplay), this, null);
```

But if you just want to append text to a textbox, you really don't need to do any of this, just put your code in DisplayData directly:

```
public void DisplayData(string msg){
   _displayWindow.Selection.Text  = string.Empty;
   _displayWindow.AppendText(msg);
   _displayWindow.ScrollToEnd();
}
```

The dispatcher is the most useful in scenarios where you are carrying out some lengthy operation on a background thread, and don't want to lock up the UI, you can use the dispatcher to send individual commands to the main thread. If you are on the UI thread, using the dispatcher doesn't really do anything useful.

If you are on a background thread, and want to update the textbox, you could do something like this:

```
public void DisplayData(string msg)
{
    _displayWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => UpdateTextbox(msg)));
}

public void UpdateTextbox(string msg)
{
    try
    {
        _displayWindow.Document.Blocks.Clear();
        _displayWindow.AppendText(msg);
        _displayWindow.ScrollToEnd();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log ex
    }
}
```